# How to print a list of lists with passed elements in a class via join method?

Tags: python, list, class, join, methods

I have code

```
class Render():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def init_screen(self, h, w):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def add_object(self, char, x, y):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def draw_screen(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_input(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

there is a task:
I need to create a ShellRenderer class that will draw the game screen in the console.

-Create a `_screen` field in it, which will be a list of character lists, size `h` by `w`.

-Initialize it with spaces when calling `init_screen` method.

-The `add_object` method must change the value of one of the `_screen` list items to a `char` character.

-The `draw_screen` method should print the list by calling `print`.

-In the `get_input` method, you can use the `input` function to get user input. Return a user-entered string.

I have almost done everything:

```
class ShellRender(Render):
    def init_screen(self, h, w):
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self._screen = [[[' '] for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]

    def add_object(self, char, x, y):
        self._screen[y][x] = char

    def draw_screen(self):
        print("\n".join(map(str, self._screen)))  # here is a mistake...

    def get_input(self):
        return input()
```

but I cannot print the list of lists in the `draw_screen` method. I think it is necessary to use `"\ n" .join (map (str, ...))` so that when `_screen = [['*', '+', '*'], ['#', '#', '#' ]]` output should be

```
*+*
###
```

But I can't write it correctly. Maybe I didn't understand the task properly, so please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
_screen = [['*', '+', '*'], ['#', '#', '#' ]]
print(*(''.join(str_arr) + '\n' for str_arr in _screen))
```

Output:

```
 *+*
 ###
```

Answer (score 1):

With `map(str, self._screen))` you are transforming the list of the row into a string. Meaning that `[1,2,3]` would become `'[1,2,3]'`.

You should join each row before printing it all out.

```
def draw_screen():
        print("\n".join(map(''.join, (_screen))))
```

Comment: And when he does `self._screen = [[[' '] for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]`, he has additional list there. The correct is `self._screen = [[' ' for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]`

Answer (score 1):

`self._screen` is a list of list, when you use `map(str, self._screen)` you are using str in a list. And there is a extra "[]" when you create screen. This will work.

```
class Render():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def init_screen(self, h, w):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def add_object(self, char, x, y):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def draw_screen(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_input(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class ShellRender(Render):
    def init_screen(self, h, w):
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self._screen = [[' ' for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]

    def add_object(self, char, x, y):
        self._screen[y][x] = char

    def draw_screen(self):
        print("\n".join(map(draw_screen_line, self._screen)))  # here is a mistake...

    def get_input(self):
        return input()

def draw_screen_line(screen_line):
    return "".join(screen_line)
```